# Replacing wildcard characters like ? in Excel

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2010, wildcards

Was is das?

I try to replace the `?` symbol to the `!` symbol in Excel (2010)... and this changes all the chars to `!`???

I try to make a conditionnal formatting for cells that contains `?` but it applyes this formatting averywhere!!

The same "feature" is with `*` symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are wildcard characters, so need to be escaped when used in cells as actual data.

Try escaping the `?` with a tilde (`~`).

eg. `~?`